# Who are the ווינדין whom the Maharil says are the Mitzrim?

Tags: history, egypt

The Maharil, brought in likutei Maharil #95 quotes his rebbi Mahara'sh as saying the nation called ווינדין are the Mitzrim (Egyptians).

> אמר מהר׳ש שקבלה בידו מאותו אומה שקורין ווינדין הם המצרים, והיינו שנאמר
>   ממלכה שפלה, כי אין להם לא שר ולא פריץ רק כולם כפריים.‏
>
> Mahara"sh said that he has a tradition that the nation that is called
>   "ווינדין" are the מצרים (Egyptians), as the verse states (יחזקאל כט,
>   יד) "a down-fallen kingdom," because they do not have any rulers; they
>   are all village dwellers.

**Who are the ווינדין that he is refering to?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Rabbi Dovid Tzvi Hillman](http://hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_26468_54.pdf) in the name of German Encyclopedia says it was a Slavic group known as [Wenden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wends) that lived in Germany.